# Creating Table in MySQL using Python 3.7, Getting Syntax Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql-python

I believe I've exhausted all options (given by current experience with MySQL which is not much) for a syntax error I get when trying to create a MySQL table in Python 3.7. Some background; I'm trying to create a table in each each loop iteration as follows:

```
index=0
for rawdat in get_WeatherData():
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE "+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m- 
    %d')+BoMList[0][index]+" (Date_Time VARCHAR(255), Wind_Speed FLOAT(12,9), 
    Rain_Trace FLOAT(12,9))")
    index+=1
```

The list `BoMList[0][index]` that is being called is a string value (weather station name if your interested) and I'm wanting the date in the table title as well.

The error I get is:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '2018-12-05S_Observatory_Hills (Date_Time VARCHAR(255),
>   Wind_Speed FLOAT(12,9), R' at line 1

Is it possible I'm using the wrong format for the MySQL syntax string:
`"CREATE TABLE "+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+BoMList[0][index]+" (Date_Time VARCHAR(255), Wind_Speed FLOAT(12,9),Rain_Trace FLOAT(12,9))"`?

I'm going off the syntax provided in: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_table.asp

Lastly `rawdat` and `get_WeatherData()` are not used until later.

Interested to hear what you guys thing, cheers.

Comment: I could imagine the dashes in the date string portion of your table name cause the issue. This character does not seem to be allowed in unquoted identifiers. Try removing them from the format string or put your table name in quote chars, i.e. backticks `.

Comment: Cheers, that seems to have worked :)